# Getting blank page and posts edit page in dashboard of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, debugging, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using woo commerce on my website and I noticed that product image field and product gallery image field was not working when I add the product but when I checked pages and posts of WordPress dashboard all those pages were also not working.

Tried all the methods like making the wp-config file debug option true, deactivating all the plugins, updating all the plugins including WordPress version but nothing seems to work.
Please help!!

Comment: and what your debug log says?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? there are no fields displayed for featured image?

Comment: I was not able to edit any of my posts and pages and product details of my shop it was showing a complete blank! but now it is solved...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
I was facing the issue because there was a defer code in functions.php file of my theme.
The code was:
//add defer to all script tag for page speed optimization
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.min.js' ) ) return $url;
return "$url ' defer ";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );